# Blender - how are points and paths imported from svg different from points and paths created in Blender?

Tags: blender

For example, I've imported a logo from Illustrator into Blender. I want to extrude the paths, but guess what? Blender refuses to do so. The "e" key only translates my shape, not extrudes it. My selection options aren't there either, so if I want to switch to line selection, or face selection, I'm out of luck.

Why does Blender treat imported points differently than native points? And is there a way to convert them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without currently having blender at hand, my guess is that blender imports SVG as curves. You now have to choices to extrude this curve:

1. Convert to mesh with <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Extrude the curve, this is done in the `Ext` field in `Geometry` in the `Object data` tab